# Como convertir un String en un archivo serializado en JAVA, para guardarlo en la BD

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy tratando de convertir un String  a tipo rchivo SerializadoBLOB en java, ya que necesito guardarlo en una tabla especifica de mi BD. Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente, pero me sigue guardando el dato siempre como un String. El String que quiero convertir a BLOB esta guardado en la variable **message**

```
LOG.info("[MESSAGE]: "+message);
        LOG.info("[CORRELATION]: "+correlation);
        LOG.info("[DBCORP_URL ]: "+dbcorp_url);
        LOG.info("[ID TRANSACCION]"+idTransaccion);
        byte[] memo = message.getBytes();
        try {
            LOG.info("Preparando Conexion");
            con = Conexion.getConexion();
            String sql = "UPDATE coop._lineaT SET memo= ? where transaccion = ?";
            pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            LOG.info("Statement Creado");           
            pstm.setBytes(1, memo);
            pstm.setString(2, idTransaccion);
            if(pstm.executeUpdate()>0) {
                LOG.info("**[TRAMAS Response INSERTADAS en BD]**");
            }else {
                pstm.close();
```

Es eso correcto??
en el campo Blob de la tabla me lo guarda tal como viene el String Original
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo esperas que se vea?

Comment: @Sal seria guardar el string en un archivo serializado... :-(

Comment: ¿Cómo esperas que se vea el archivo serializado?

Comment: Incluso un archivo serializado de Java deja ver los textos reales, establecer un campo en la base de datos como BLOB, VARBINARY O BINARY no "parsea" lo se vaya a guardar al tipo de dato. Aunque hay un comportamiento extraño que no comprendo y es que el array de bytes te muestra en si el byte (no el char), pero al guardarlo en la base de datos te muestra la letra en sí.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problema creando una clase generica para Serializar un objeto

```
package com.ba.util;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
//OBJETOS A BYTE[]
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class SerializadorBinario {
    private String logerror;
    //Serializar Objeto como archivo
        private java.io.ObjectOutputStream escritorOBJ;

    //Serializar Objeto a Arreglo de Bytes
        private java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream salida_bytes;
        
    //Recibe un objeto y retorna un arreglo de bytes
        public byte[] SerializarToBytes(Object obj) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = null;
                salida_bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                escritorOBJ = new ObjectOutputStream(salida_bytes);
                escritorOBJ.writeObject(obj);
                escritorOBJ.flush();
                bytes = salida_bytes.toByteArray();
                escritorOBJ.close();
                salida_bytes.close();
                return bytes;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.logerror = ex.getMessage();
                return new byte[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

la implemente en mi codigo de la siguiente manera, donde message contiene el String a serializar:

```
LOG.info("Preparando Conexion");
            byte[] bytes;
            SerializadorBinario serializador = new SerializadorBinario();
            bytes = serializador.SerializarToBytes(message);
```

para hacer el insert en la tabla de mi BD con prepareStatement

```
pstm.setBytes(4, bytes);
```